# How to set JSON response to views programatically in Android?

Tags: android, json

I have created an app in which I am fetching data from server. So, I have used JSON parsing in my code. I am successfully parsed my JSON from server.

Actually I want to make a questions and options base quiz application. So that, I have five entries in my database named question_id, question_title, option 1, option 2, option 3, option 4. I want to display all these widgets at run time.

I am getting JSON response right.But I am displaying my data.

Here is my QuizActivity file

```
package com.aquib.quiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://labs.kamkazi.com/quiz/quiz.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "quiz";
    private static final String TAG_QUESTIONID = "question_id";
    private static final String TAG_QUESTIONTITLE = "question_title";
    private static final String TAG_OPTION1 = "option1";
    private static final String TAG_OPTION2 = "option2";
    private static final String TAG_OPTION3 = "option3";
    private static final String TAG_OPTION4 = "option4";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuizActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String questionTitle = c.getString(TAG_QUESTIONTITLE);
                        String option1 = c.optString(TAG_OPTION1);
                        String option2 = c.optString(TAG_OPTION2);
                        String option3 = c.optString(TAG_OPTION3);
                        String option4 = c.optString(TAG_OPTION4);
                        String questionid = c.optString(TAG_QUESTIONID);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        map.put(TAG_QUESTIONID, questionid);
                        map.put(TAG_QUESTIONTITLE, questionTitle);
                        map.put(TAG_OPTION1, option1);
                        map.put(TAG_OPTION2, option2);
                        map.put(TAG_OPTION3, option3);
                        map.put(TAG_OPTION4, option4);

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No quiz found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    myToast.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
            myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


            TextView myView = new TextView(getBaseContext());
            myView.setText(TAG_QUESTIONTITLE);
            myView.setPadding(5, 10, 0, 0);

            myLayout.addView(myView);

        }

    }
}
```

Please also help me in creating radio buttons programatically.

Comment: parse all the question when the page loads, the add questions, option s to different array list, then in button click next and previous show the corresponding question to the user, if user selects an option then save that on database, at last send the data to server and show the result in another activity

Comment: @GeorgeThomas when i have stored options in database.Now i want to display the score of player.I have two tables in my database one contained question title and options and other has stored answer.

Comment: save the question id and corresponding answer of each question user selected in a table 
and when user press submit button ,send it to server ask them to give total score as response ,parse the reponse and show it in another page

Comment: @GeorgeThomas You mean that should i code to calculate score at server side.and then parse this score in json response and then display on my app.

Comment: exactly...that may be a good option

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create checkbox

```
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.checkgroup);
for (int i = 0; i < Array_Count; i++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    checkBox = new CheckBox(getActivity());

    checkBox.setId(i);
    noofcheckbox++;
    checkBox.setText(ans[i]);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            name();
        }
    });
    row.addView(checkBox);
    my_layout.addView(row);
}
```

Try out this to add radio button dynamically.
ans(array that contains the option)

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
    RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    radiobutton.setText(ans[i]);
    radiobutton.setId(150 + i);
    rg.addView(radiobutton);
}
```